# undefined method `edit_..._path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I have this in a rails 4 html.erb template.

```
  <% @super_categories.each do |super_category| %>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <%= link_to "Edit", edit_admin_super_category(super_category.id), class: "button tiny" %>
          </li>
       </ul>    
    <% end %>
```

There is no problem with @super_categories instance variable and edit has been defined in the controller. I also have edit_admin_super_category as part of my routes when I run rake routes. For some reason, it keeps on giving me:
**undefined method `edit_admin_super_category'**

I just don't get what I am doing wrong here. Anybody spotting it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Route paths will end in `_path` or `_url` (eg. `edit_admin_super_category_path(super_category.id)`).

If you make that change and you're still getting that error, please post your routes - you likely don't have one that matches that name.